# Reactjs - Can't get value from array, undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to compare the values from 2 state arrays, but when I look at the value of `otherItems[i]` I get `undefined`. For clarification, `Items` is an array of Objects with many data points, why I'm calling it with `.name`, while `otherItems` is just an array of the names. If I call just `this.state.otherItems` then I get the full array contents.

```
this.state = {
  Items: [],
  otherItems: [],
  ...
}
...
function = () => {
  var total = this.state.total;
  var i;
  for(i = 0; i < this.state.Items.length; i++) {
    console.log(this.state.otherItems[i]);
    if(this.state.Items[i].name === this.state.otherItems[i]) {
      total += parseFloat(this.state.Items[i].price)
    }
  }
  this.setState({Total: total})
}
```

What I would like to happen is the items from the two arrays compare, and the price of the item is added to the total sum if and only if the item `i` from `Items` exists in `otherItems`.

Comment: You are logging `basketItems[i]`, not `otherItems[i]`. Is that what you mean gives you `undefined`?

Comment: @Tholle ah sorry that was a type, should be otherItems. I fixed it now.

Comment: You have a typo in  `console.log(this.state.otehrItems[i]);` it should be `console.log(this.state.otherItems[i]);`

Comment: Alright. Could you clarify what it is you are trying to accomplish? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as it will make it a lot easier for someone to help you.

Comment: @NilsKähler Yes that was another typo I made when I made an edit.

Comment: And if you log `console.log(this.state.otherItems);` in the same place that you do `console.log(this.state.otherItems[i]);` you get the full array? and otherwise `undefined`

Comment: @NilsKähler Yes, if I do that then I get the full array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a loop variable `i` and using that to index both arrays, so you are only comparing elements with the same index between the two arrays, and the two arrays might differ in length.

You could instead use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if the `name` of an element in `Items` is present in the `otherItems` array.

```
getTotal() {
  this.setState(({ total = 0, Items, otherItems }) => {
    Items.forEach(item => {
      if (this.state.otherItems.includes(item.name)) {
        total += parseFloat(item.price);
      }
    });

    return { otherTotal: total };
  });
}
```

Comment: very good answer with prevState implemented to avoid async conflits

Comment: I tried this, but for some odd reason `total` returns as `NaN` or `Not a Number`.

Comment: @taway0282 Alright. Could you include all relevant code in your question? It might be that it's called `Total` instead of `total`, or something else that the current code doesn't show.

Comment: If there are any small inconsistencies, such as `total` instead of `Total` it's not the actual problem, just a transcription mistake. In the code editor it's the correct variable name.

Comment: This worked with minor tweaks, thank you very much :) Should I post the tweaked version as an edit or how should I go about this?

Comment: @taway0282 You're welcome. You can edit my answer with the changes, tell me what the changes were and I'll change them, or post your own answer.